# trying to install expo

Tags: react-native, expo

i use mac os calina ver 10.15.3
i run :
npm install -g expo-cli
i have error :

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see request/request#3142
```

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see request/request#3142
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.

@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.13.1 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin
node platform.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.13.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.13.1: wanted {"os":"win32,linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @expo/image-utils@0.2.18 requires a peer of sharp-cli@^1.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/expo
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/expo'
npm ERR! [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/expo'] {
npm ERR! cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/expo'] {
npm ERR! errno: -13,
npm ERR! code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR! path: '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js',
npm ERR! dest: '/usr/local/bin/expo'
npm ERR! },
npm ERR! stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/expo'",
npm ERR! errno: -13,
npm ERR! code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR! path: '../lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js',
npm ERR! dest: '/usr/local/bin/expo'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/duclong/.npm/_logs/2020-04-09T19_09_53_271Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the node package. Upgrade node version.

Answer (score 0):

The error message itself is telling you what to do. It is a permission error. EACCES is always a permission error. It tries to setup symlinks for `/usr/local/bin/expo` but it can’t. Try running the command with `sudo`, like `sudo npm i -g expo-cli`. If it does not help, try to reinstall node completely. I recommend `nvm` for installing and managing node versions.